# Publisher name and address(country) inside bracket

Tags: bibtex

I am new in the bst, I am trying to edit apa bibliography style file (bst) such that it needs publisher name and address(country) inside bracket, If publisher is empty then address(country) should be inside bracket, If address(country) is empty then publisher should be inside bracket, below code is not working and it's shows error also so somebody help me please

```
FUNCTION {format.publisher}
{ publisher empty$
    { "" }
    { "(" swap$ *
      address empty$
      {")"*}
      { swap$ ")" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I deleted the [tag:latex3] tag, since it is not related to your question

Comment: I also deleted the `biblatex` tag since you are clearly using BibTeX with `.bst` styles and so definitely not `biblatex`.

Comment: A complete minimal (non)working example would be nice. That way everyone who wants to help doesn't have to build it on his own.

Comment: Would you consider using `biblatex`? It's easier to customise.